# GeoJSON interaction with leaflet

Tags: leaflet, geojson, ajax

I want to list GeoJSON on map as well on the div element outside the map but I'm somehow stuck.

Using this block of code I did manage to create some sort of interaction between map and div element outside of map.

```
// Create or retrieve the data
var DOF = L.tileLayer.wms(" http://geoportal.dgu.hr/wms?", {
    layers: 'DOF'
});




var people = $.getJSON("php/rasvjeta_150n.php", function (data) {
});
// var people = JSON.parse(geojson);

// let people = [
//     {
//       name: 'FIRST POINT',
//       latLng: [46.210888, 15.647540],
//       id: '2342fc7'
//     },
//     {
//       name: 'SECOND POINT',
//       latLng: [46.211888, 15.647540],
//       id: 'djf3892'
//     },
//     {
//       name: 'THIRD POINT',
//       latLng: [46.2120888, 15.647540],
//       id: '2837hf3'
//     }
// ];

// Create the group
let group = L.layerGroup(),
    list = document.getElementById('list')

// Create the map
var map = L.map('map',{
        center:[46.15796, 15.75336],
        zoom:13,
        layers: DOF
        });


// Loop through the data
Object.keys(people).forEach(person => {
  let marker = L.marker(person.latLng, {
    icon: L.icon({
        iconUrl: "img/power_green.png",
        iconSize: [20, 28],
        iconAnchor: [12, 28],
        popupAnchor: [0, -25]
      }),
        title: person.name,
        riseOnHover: true
      });

  // Add each marker to the group
  group.addLayer( marker );

  // Save the ID of the marker with it's data
  person.marker_id = group.getLayerId(marker);
})

// Add the group to the map
group.addTo(map);

// Click handler for handling
function onClick(data) {
  let { marker_id } = data,
      marker = group.getLayer(marker_id);

  map.panTo( marker.getLatLng() );
}

// Append list items
people.forEach(person => {
  let item = document.createElement('ul');

  item.innerHTML = `<a href="#" class="list-group-item">${person.name}<br><b>CODE: </b>${person.x}</a>`;
  item.addEventListener('click', onClick.bind(null, person));

  list.appendChild(item);
});
```

But when I try to use PHP generated GeoJSON using this

```
 var people = $.getJSON("php/rasvjeta_150n.php", function (data) {
    });
```

PHP code is working fine.
I get this type of error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'lat' of undefined`

I've copied working example from [this](http://codepen.io/gvenech/pen/QEjEGg) site

---

Here is generated GeoJSON from PHP

```
{  
   "type":"FeatureCollection",
   "features":[  
      {  
         "type":"Feature",
         "geometry":{  
            "type":"Point",
            "coordinates":[  
               15.73141861,
               46.15459061
            ]
         },
         "properties":{  
            "ts_sifra":"TPR012",
            "ts_naziv":"Krapina 5",
            "sifra_lampe":"A3-12",
            "vrsta_stupa":"\u017deljezni kandelaber",
            "tip_lampe":"Refletkor LED 100W",
            "naziv_naselja":"Grletinec",
            "adresa":"Kajba 1"
         }
      },
      {  
         "type":"Feature",
         "geometry":{  
            "type":"Point",
            "coordinates":[  
               15.72079945,
               46.13504791
            ]
         },
         "properties":{  
            "ts_sifra":"TPR070",
            "ts_naziv":"Pri\u0161lin 2",
            "sifra_lampe":"D10",
            "vrsta_stupa":"Drveni",
            "tip_lampe":"70W Natrij",
            "naziv_naselja":"Pri\u0161lin",
            "adresa":"Stipernica 1"
         }
      },
      {  
         "type":"Feature",
         "geometry":{  
            "type":"Point",
            "coordinates":[  
               15.86748695,
               46.1628685
            ]
         },
         "properties":{  
            "ts_sifra":"TPR070",
            "ts_naziv":"Pri\u0161lin 2",
            "sifra_lampe":"H10",
            "vrsta_stupa":"\u017deljezni kandelaber",
            "tip_lampe":"Refletkor LED 100W",
            "naziv_naselja":"Hum na Sutli",
            "adresa":"Krapina 23"
         }
      },
      {  
         "type":"Feature",
         "geometry":{  
            "type":"Point",
            "coordinates":[  
               15.64838982,
               46.20975876
            ]
         },
         "properties":{  
            "ts_sifra":"TPR070",
            "ts_naziv":"Pri\u0161lin 2",
            "sifra_lampe":"D6",
            "vrsta_stupa":"Betonski",
            "tip_lampe":"70W Natrij",
            "naziv_naselja":"Pri\u0161lin",
            "adresa":"Pri\u0161lin 90"
         }
      },
      {  
         "type":"Feature",
         "geometry":{  
            "type":"Point",
            "coordinates":[  
               15.64866161,
               46.20946503
            ]
         },
         "properties":{  
            "ts_sifra":"TPR070",
            "ts_naziv":"Pri\u0161lin 2",
            "sifra_lampe":"D5",
            "vrsta_stupa":"Betonski",
            "tip_lampe":"150W Natrij",
            "naziv_naselja":"Pri\u0161lin",
            "adresa":"Pri\u0161lin 67"
         }
      },
      {  
         "type":"Feature",
         "geometry":{  
            "type":"Point",
            "coordinates":[  
               15.64934731,
               46.2098732
            ]
         },
         "properties":{  
            "ts_sifra":"TPR070",
            "ts_naziv":"Pri\u0161lin 2",
            "sifra_lampe":"D4",
            "vrsta_stupa":"Betonski",
            "tip_lampe":"150W Natrij",
            "naziv_naselja":"Pri\u0161lin",
            "adresa":"Pri\u0161lin 65"
         }
      },
      {  
         "type":"Feature",
         "geometry":{  
            "type":"Point",
            "coordinates":[  
               15.64995384,
               46.20995712
            ]
         },
         "properties":{  
            "ts_sifra":"TPR070",
            "ts_naziv":"Pri\u0161lin 2",
            "sifra_lampe":"D3",
            "vrsta_stupa":"Betonski",
            "tip_lampe":"150W Natrij",
            "naziv_naselja":"Pri\u0161lin",
            "adresa":"Pri\u0161lin 63"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it is a asynchronous issue: your function `$.getJSON` does not ends before the remainder of the code is executed. Therefore, the object `people` actually doesn't exist when your code want to use it.

- A solution is to put all the remainder of your code into the function $.getJSON:

  > $.getJSON( /*All your code here */)

but this solution won't work if your geojson and javascript files are in different domains, because of same-origin policy browsers' restrictions.

- Therefore, another solution is to use this plugin that makes an AJAX call for calling geojson in LeafletJS:  https://github.com/calvinmetcalf/leaflet-ajax

The whole story is better explained here: http://lyzidiamond.com/posts/external-geojson-and-leaflet-the-other-way

Answer (score 1):

Use [L.geojson.ajax](https://github.com/calvinmetcalf/leaflet-ajax) to create a Geojson layer from php. Then you can use `onEachFeature` property to set the markers and use the `layers builtin events` to handle clicks. This way the code will be more intuitive and manageable.